# What happens when I get a Skin for a Hero I don't own?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday, I convinced a friend to play LoL. He inserted my username, when the system asked if he was referred by someone.

Then I saw there are rewards for each friend you refer.

[image: LoL Friend Referral Rewards]

**My question is:**

I have neither Warwick nor Twitch. Can I get the skins anyway? Do I need to have these two champions to get them? If I buy the champions a few days later do I have the skins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Refer_A_Friend#Version_3.0) states that you will get the champion and the skin. Although this is no highly official source it's usually correct. Also: Reward skins come with the champion in League of Legends.

Triumphant Tyze, Riot Tristana, Unchained Alistar and Victorious skins all reward you with the skin **and** the champion. I wouldn't see a reason why this is any different here.

Comment: so.. if I get the skins i get the champions too? for free?

Comment: @msm.oliveira yep. Skins always come bundled with champions if they're rewarded.